# QThread doesn't provide output from called shellscript

Tags: c++, bash, qt, shell

I have a function that executes system calls and writes the output into a `QTextEdit`.

```cpp
string SystemCallFactory::runSysCallWithoutButton(unique_ptr<SystemCall> sysCall)
{
  cout << "Running " << sysCall->getCommand() << endl;

  textEdit->setText("");
  textEdit->repaint();

  QProcess process;
  process.start(QString::fromStdString(sysCall->getCommand()));
  process.waitForFinished();
  QString output(process.readAllStandardOutput());

  textEdit->append(output);
  textEdit->repaint();

  return output.toStdString();
}
```

The problem is that this works when `getCommand()` is a *real* command, e.g. `ls /etc` but does not work correctly when it refers to a shellscript. In my calls, the call that does not work looks like

```
/home/turtle10000/tilematching.sh /some/folder /some/specific.file
```

The script gets executed and does what it's supposed to do, but `readAllStandardOutput()` returns an empty string. When I run it in a terminal, it shows the expected output.

This is the shellscript:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -v

WORKSPACE=$1
SVPFILE=$2

cd $WORKSPACE
ls -1 *.all > datalist.0.mb-1

mbset -I datalist.0.mb-1 -PSVPMODE:1 -PSVPFILE:$SVPFILE
mbprocess -I datalist.0.mb-1
ls -1 *p.mb58 > datalist.1.mb-1

mbset -I datalist.1.mb-1 -PSONAROFFSETX:-0.079 -PSONAROFFSETY:0.196 -PSONAROFFSETZ:0.048 -PVRUOFFSETX:-0.4473 -PVRUOFFSETY:0.000 -PVRUOFFSETZ:-0.3395 -PROLLBIAS:0.1 -PPITCHBIAS:1.32
mbprocess -I datalist.1.mb-1
ls -1 *pp.mb58 > datalist.2.mb-1

mblist -I datalist.2.mb-1 -MA -O^X^Y-z -JU > output.xyz 

#remove broken lines (error in input files)
sed -ie '/      /d' output.xyz
```

Edit: as [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) guessed, some of output appears in stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the shell process with the script as the argument: _process.start("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "path/to/script.sh");_

Comment: No, but great idea. Will test, thanks!

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: If you run `/home/turtle10000/tilematching.sh /some/folder /some/specific.file 2>/dev/null` in your shell, does any output appear? If not, all your "output" appears on the standard *error* stream.

Comment: @Botje YES, that's it! Thank you, I can catch it with `readAllStandardError()` as a workaround. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Now, the next question is, why does it behave like this? I'll edit this as an follow up.

Comment: Ask whoever wrote `mbset` and `mbprocess` :)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `mbset` and `mbprocess` are parts of mb-system seafloor mapping software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) suggested, I checked if the output went to stderr and it did. For whatever reason, the output of `mbset` and `mbprocess`, tools from the [mb-system](https://www.mbari.org/products/research-software/mb-system/) package, goes to stderr.

In this case, I changed the line

```cpp
QString output(process.readAllStandardOutput());
```

to

```cpp
QString output(process.readAllStandardError());
```

Another option would probably be to channel the stderr output to stdout in the script.